# Create WriteableBitmap using HTML content in Windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Create WriteableBitmap using HTML content in Windows phone 8.1 Without involving the XAML

I have created WebView object in c# and render HTML content in WebView.NaviagateToString and trying to get the object using WebView.CapturePreviewToStreamAsync method but i am getting the Global exception ( value does not fall within the expected range).

```
WebView wv = new WebView();
wv.NavigateToString(HTML Content);
InMemoryRandomAccessStream imras = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
await wv.CapturePreviewToStreamAsync(imras);
```

And also i tried using the below code, but i didn't find the dlls.

```
Bitmap m_Bitmap = new Bitmap(400, 600);
PointF point = new PointF(0, 0);
SizeF maxSize = new System.Drawing.SizeF(500, 500);
HtmlRenderer.HtmlRender.Render(Graphics.FromImage(m_Bitmap),"<html><body><p>This is a shitty html code</p><p>This is another html line</p></body>", point,maxSize);
m_Bitmap.Save(@"C:\Test.bmp")
```

Please help me out from this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

t's impossible currently, Windows Phone Store apps do have a phone-only ScreenCapture API, but it still need to show your content in you app.

We are trying to better understand customer views on social support experience, so your participation in this interview project would be greatly appreciated if you have time. Thanks for helping make community forums a great place.